# Trouble with Personal project code (replacing characters)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm setting up a personal project for a group of friends and i get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users[my pc name]\Downloads\Python  code\meme documentation.py", line 11, in 
    line = line.re(char,'')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 're'

i have had a look over the internet and couldn't find anything related to the problem i have. Here's my code:

```py
import re
name = input("What is the name of this meme?")
age = input("How Old is this meme?")
purpose = str(input("please state the purpose of this meme: (if there is none, reply with 'N/A'"))

wholeAssDocumentation = ("This meme is known as the" , name , "and it is" , age , "years old. Its purpose was:" , purpose)
print = (wholeAssDocumentation)

line = (wholeAssDocumentation)  
for char in "( ?.!/;:)'":  
    line = line.re(char,'')
```

Expected: it deletes the characters listed from the string entirely (as it appears in the text file i have it write to)

```
Actual: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[my pc name]\Downloads\Python  code\meme documentation.py", line 11, in <module>
    line = line.re(char,'')
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 're'
```

Comment: `line = line.re(char,'')` what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to replace the characters listed with a " " (space)

Comment: `print = (wholeAssDocumentation)` ??  Start here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: i was going to remove that as it was only for testing purposes, then just didn't remove it.

Comment: That is not how to use a print function either .... Please - lookup a basic tutorial and follow it through to get the basics straight.

Comment: i tried this in a new compiler and it worked, completely fine:
```
test = ("this is a test")
print (test)
```
which is what i had done in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, tuples are defined with `tup = (val1,val2,...)`. This is what you're doing when you define `wholeAssDocumentation`. Since tuples don't have a re method, you're getting that error.

Other than that, I suggest you read the regex documentation because that's not how you use a regex on a string either.

Also you're overwriting the print function for some reason

Comment: i was going to remove the print function as it was only for testing purposes, then just didn't remove it.

Answer (score 0):

1. `wholeAssDocumentation` is a tuple, which you know because you created it.
2. You assigned it to `line`, so `line` is as well.
3. You tried to execute the `re` method/function of `line`, which does not exist, as the error clearly states.

Where did you get the idea that tuples have an `re` method?

Comment: i thought that, by using line, it would be a string, and as i cannot use tuples in a string. i remember seeing an old post that suggested using re but it doesn't work.